# Buenas, soy estudiante de DAM y nos han mandado replicar esta estructura de commits y merge y no consigo hacerla. Llevo horas y no hay manera.!

Tags: git

Enunciado:

Contexto:

Estás liderando un equipo de desarrollo para un proyecto de una aplicación web.

El proyecto tiene dos funcionalidades principales: **Funcionalidad_A** y **Funcionalidad_B**. Además, hay una rama de `Release` para preparar versiones, la master para publicar y una rama de `Hotfix` para corregir errores críticos.

Debes conseguir esta estructura de commits y merges: En los mensajes puedes ver qué se ha hecho en cada commit y siguiendo los caminos sabrás en qué rama, y cómo han sido y cuándo los merges.

[image: 1]

He intentado:

1. Crear el primer commit en git (creo que la rama se llama release).
2. Sobre release he subido el reade.md
3. Partiendo de release he creado la rama funcionlidad_a.
4. Mergeo fuincionalidad_A sobre release.
5. Después he creado la rama `hotfix` sobre release y ser mergea con release.
6. Del primer commit de release he creado un fichero fb.txt.
7. He creado una rama a partir del primer commit modificado con fb.txt. y se le añadido una linea a fb.txt.
8. He mergeado la funcionalidad_b sobre release pero release release. con funcionalidad_a 9-Mergeo todo sobre release con los cambios de hotfix, fa y fb.

Comment: Bienvenido. Qué intentaste?

Comment: 1-Crear el primer commit en git (creo que la rama se llama release)     2-Sobre release he subido el reade.md 3-Partiendo de release he creado la rama funcionlidad_a 4- Mergeo fuincionalidad_A sobre release 5- Después he creado la rama hotfix sobre release y ser mergea con release 6- Del primer commit de release he creado un fichero fb.txt 7- He creado una rama a partir del primer commit modificado con fb.txt y se le añadido una linea a fb.txt 8- He mergeado la funcionalidad_b sobre release pero release release con funcionalidad_a 9-Mergeo todo sobre release con los cambios de hotfix, fa y fb.